Strange performance issue with Where and Endswith, 7 times slower with .NET 8 than with .NET Framework
I discovered a strange performance issue with the following statement, after upgrading the solution from .NET Framework to .NET 8, I've got performance degradation about 7 times slower.
I'm iterating a class list with about 1000 items, it gets me about 0.2ms on average for each call with .NET Framework 4.5.1, where as it takes 1.3ms with .NET 8 - same system, iteration logic and dev environment. Release build isn't much faster.
return _Values.Where(w => w.Name.EndsWith(key))
              .DefaultIfEmpty(ConfigurationValue.Empty).First();

_Values is a simple list of values:
List<ConfigurationValue> _Values;

ConfigurationValue is a simple class holding the name of a value:
public class ConfigurationValue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the configuration value
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [...]
}

I know, the loop could be enhanced with binary search algorithms anyways, but I wasn't prepared that .NET Core degrades in performance on such tasks which where proven with accepted performance.
Does anybody know about the implementation changes in the frameworks for the Where and EndsWith methods?

You should make an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues describing the regression and the benchmark methodology

Does anybody know about the implementation changes in the frameworks for the Where and EndsWith methods - yes. Also https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48812 specifically.

Thanks, the ligustic search methology, which changed with Net Core as being the default for EndsWith and other comparison methods, was exactly the reason and I missed that part in the change docs of Net Core!

I strongly suspect this is due to cultural checks that go through different code paths in .NET Framework and .NET. If you're happy with an ordinal check, you should try this instead:
return _Values.Where(w => w.Name.EndsWith(key, StringComparer.Ordinal))
              .DefaultIfEmpty(ConfigurationValue.Empty).First();

Not only is that faster, but it means it'll behave consistently on all systems. (Of course, that might not be what you want...)
That may well be much faster. I had a similar issue back in 2016 where NUnit was using EndsWith without an explicit comparer.
As an aside, you can also combine the "first, but with a default value" parts:
return _Values.Where(w => w.Name.EndsWith(key, StringComparer.Ordinal))
              .FirstOrDefault(ConfigurationValue.Empty);

I doubt that that'll make any performance difference, but personally I think it's a tiny bit tidier :)

Thanks, that perfectly resolved the issue! And for this case, being a searcher method for a technical key of a database, I need the ordinal search methology!
